# TypeError: post_request() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'token' and 'uuid'

Tags: python

So as information I tried to make a script to check if the SessionID is valid in Minecraft and then send it to a webhook.

```
File "c:\Users\PC\Desktop\RandomShit\dhook.py", line 43, in <module>
    isValid = post_request()
TypeError: post_request() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'token' and 'uuid'
```

So this is the code but for some reason it just doesn't work, I'm pretty new to python and coding in general and need help with this.

```
from cgitb import text
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed
import requests
import json

hook = Webhook('https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1000036496658669619/OChDQ2Whz86jlIrXDelDUUybjQ0DPXkEWRB9QRInBJb18Ww4W-NPo_ZM_fVwnHQ88gh0')
token = "Token Here"
uuid = "UUID Here"

def send(token, uuid):
#embed json
  embed = Embed(
    title= "Token Validator",
    color=0x68228B,
    timestamp='now'  # sets the timestamp to current time
    )



  embed.add_field(name='UUID', value=uuid, inline='false')
  embed.add_field(name='Token', value=token, inline='false')


  hook.send(embed=embed)

def post_request(token, uuid):
    url = "https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/join"
    payload = {
        "accessToken": token,
        "selectedProfile": uuid,
        "serverId": uuid
    }
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': "application/json"
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 204:
        return True
    else:
        print(response.text)
        return False

isValid = post_request()
if isValid:
    print("token is valid")
    send(token, uuid)
else:
    print("token is invalid")
```

All the help I can get is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to pass `token, uuid` into the `request` function

```py
from cgitb import text
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed
import requests
import json

hook = Webhook('https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1000036496658669619/OChDQ2Whz86jlIrXDelDUUybjQ0DPXkEWRB9QRInBJb18Ww4W-NPo_ZM_fVwnHQ88gh0')
token = "Token Here"
uuid = "UUID Here"

def send(token, uuid):
#embed json
  embed = Embed(
    title= "Token Validator",
    color=0x68228B,
    timestamp='now'  # sets the timestamp to current time
    )



  embed.add_field(name='UUID', value=uuid, inline='false')
  embed.add_field(name='Token', value=token, inline='false')


  hook.send(embed=embed)

def post_request(token, uuid):
    url = "https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/join"
    payload = {
        "accessToken": token,
        "selectedProfile": uuid,
        "serverId": uuid
    }
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': "application/json"
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 204:
        return True
    else:
        print(response.text)
        return False

isValid = post_request(token, uuid) # add this here
if isValid:
    print("token is valid")
    send(token, uuid)
else:
    print("token is invalid")
```